# What is the "proper" way to implement a common UIAlertView for multiple view controllers?

Tags: ios

I'm learning iOS development and am working on a simple application. I have two view controllers, `ViewC_0` and `ViewC_1`, that are managed by a navigation controller. For both ViewCs, I have a button that will pop up a `UIAlertView` to prompt the user for a password. Everything about the UIAlertView is the same between `ViewC_0` and `ViewC_1` except for the `alertView:theAlert:clickedButtonAtIndex` selector since they will naturally perform different actions. I also would like the passwords to be different.

Even though this is relatively simple and doesn't take a lot of code, I didn't want to duplicate it across the two view controllers. My thoughts on possible ways to commonize the UIAlertView code were

1. Create a ViewController class called `PasswordViewController` and have `ViewC_0` and `ViewC_1` be subclasses of that. They would then use methods in the super class for managing the UIAlertView.
2. Create a class that inherits from NSObject and specifies a protocol. Something like:
       #import

   ```
   @protocol AlertHelperProtocol <NSObject>
   @required
   - (void)actionForValidPassword;

   @optional
   @end

   @interface AlertHelper : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
   - (id)initWithPassword:(NSString *)password andDelegate:(id)target;
   - (void)promptForPassword;
   @end
   ```

Is there a proper or standard approach to this in iOS development? The latter approach seems cleaner to me, although I'm not sure what happens if a class tries to use the AlertHelper that doesn't have an active View. It also allowed me to learn about protocols and delegates, so that was nice.

Comment: There is no proper way, there is just the way you like to do that. Your question is more about personal opinion and preferences.